# How to boost to load multiple images from web to ImageViews

Tags: java, android, performance, android-networking, android-threading

To load several images from a website, the following code was written.

```
    public void connectImgtoView(final int max) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URL url = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    try {
                        url = new URL(postImgUrl.get(i));
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream
                                = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
                        bufferedInputStream.close();

                        final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                bitmap,
                                (int) (992),
                                (int) (1403),
                                true
                        );

                        final int finalI = i;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                postImg[finalI].setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                progressOFF();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Although this method is performed successfully, there is a problem that the performance speed is too slow.

So I want to know what is faster than this method.

Please help me.

Variable description

postImgUrl : type is ArrayList, this is url that has image i want

postImg : type is ImageView Array, this is ImageView that exists in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the for loop out side of `Thread` so that you can instantiate and work multiple `Threads` simultaneously.

```
public void connectImgtoView(final int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(postImgUrl.get(i));
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream
                                = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
                        bufferedInputStream.close();

                        final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                bitmap,
                                (int) (992),
                                (int) (1403),
                                true
                        );

                        final int finalI = i;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                postImg[finalI].setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                progressOFF();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```